# Index Management page showing blank in admin panel

Tags: magento-1, error, upgrade, indexing

I am having this issue, Index page is showing blank page. I recently updated my website from Magento **1.6** to Magento **1.9.3.3**.

Comment: Did you try reindexed by CLI?

Comment: To find out, what causes a blank page, please refer to the linked duplicate. If you have found the actual error message and it does not help you, feel free to update the answer

Answer (score 1):

This can be caused by unexpected termination of previous reindex.

Try to reindex with SSH like this:

```
php -f shell/indexer.php reindexall
```

OR:

```
php shell/indexer.php --reindex catalog_product_attribute
php shell/indexer.php --reindex catalog_product_price
php shell/indexer.php --reindex catalog_url
php shell/indexer.php --reindex catalog_product_flat
php shell/indexer.php --reindex catalog_category_flat
php shell/indexer.php --reindex catalog_category_product
php shell/indexer.php --reindex catalogsearch_fulltext
php shell/indexer.php --reindex cataloginventory_stock
```